# Using webpack compiled library as external in CLJS

Tags: clojure, webpack, clojurescript, cljsbuild

I have some legacy code which uses D3 and is compiled with webpack. 
I'm toying with the idea of porting the D3 bits as external library, and wrapping them as a reagent/re-frame component, yet I have problems importing the JS bits.

I created a small project which demonstrates the problem:

- The JS library [code](https://github.com/fbielejec/wrap-stateful/blob/feature/use-in-cljs/js/src/index.js) .
- The webpack [config](https://github.com/fbielejec/wrap-stateful/blob/feature/use-in-cljs/js/webpack.config.js) used to (UMD) compile it.
- The [compiled](https://github.com/fbielejec/wrap-stateful/blob/feature/use-in-cljs/js/lib/d3-lib.js) library (without minify for readability).

Now in a JS project I would use the library like this:

```
import * as module from 'd3-lib.js'

var m = new module.Module()

m.setData("miserables.json").render();
```

I tried to mimick that:

- I specify the ns the library provides using [foreign-libs](https://github.com/fbielejec/wrap-stateful/blob/feature/use-in-cljs/project.clj#L29) in project.clj.
- [Import](https://github.com/fbielejec/wrap-stateful/blob/feature/use-in-cljs/src/cljs/wrap_stateful/views.cljs#L4%0A) the library.
- Instantiate via the [JS-interop](https://github.com/fbielejec/wrap-stateful/blob/feature/use-in-cljs/src/cljs/wrap_stateful/views.cljs#L39)

Yet I keep getting:

> Uncaught Error: goog.require could not find: d3_lib

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the d3 package from cljsjs ?

> Using the cljsjs/d3 package
>
> Add the dependency coordinates [cljsjs/d3 "4.3.0-5"] to the list of :dependencies in your project.
>      Make sure to require cljsjs.d3 somewhere in your project so it is added to your compiled ClojureScript code.
>
> (ns your.namespace
>        (:require [cljsjs.d3]))
>
> You can now use your newly added library by accessing it through the global Javascript namespace, e.g.js/ReactPlease check the project's documentation to find out what global the library uses. Please note: You can not use :as or :refer with CLJSJS dependencies.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thank you for your answer. I am aware of the CLJS project and the concept of externs, yet the situation here is a bit different - the webpack library (d3-lib) is already compiled with webpack i.e. it contains the D3 bits (stripped of unused code - see the third URL I posted in my question). It's supposed to act as a self-contained vizualisation (with fluent API) ready to be plugged-in in cljs or node.js project (the example I posted off course is minimal, the library in fact is a lot bigger, but the concept stays the same).